# Why can you style some HTML elements with CSS but not with attributes

Tags: html, css, attributes

As I was scrolling through some [w3schools](https://w3schools.com) documentations I came across a section about `inline` elements and a question I never really thought about before. The docs say the following:

> #### Inline Elements
>
> An `inline` element does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary.
>
> ```
> | <a> | <abbr> | <acronym> | <b> | <bdo> | <big> | <br> | <button> | <cite> | <code> | <q> |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | <dfn> | <em> | <i> | <img> | <input> | <kbd> | <label> | <map> | <object> | <output>     |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | <samp> | <script> | <select> | <small> | <span> | <strong> | <sub> | <sup> | <textarea>  |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | <time> | <tt> | <var> |                                                                  |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

What I am interested in is the [`<input>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) element. Further down the page all attributes the element takes are explained. 
The [`height`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_height.asp) attribute is explained as:

> Specifies the height of an `<input>` element (only for `type="image"`)

Yes, I know that the attribute will be ignored in this code:

```html
<input type="text" height="500" value="Nothing changed">
```

Of course, I would just use CSS for this but why does CSS even work and the HTML attribute doesn't?

```css
input {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="I feel so thicc :(">
```

So I wonder why this is. There was a decision made that `inline` elements can't have `height` attributes and others (not `inline`) can. What is the point of removing the height attribute if CSS can style it anyway it?

Comment: _“Why does CSS even work and the HTML attribute doesn’t?”_ — Why shouldn’t the CSS work? Why should the attribute work? There’s no one-to-one correspondence between HTML attributes and CSS properties.

Comment: only for `type="image"` your input has a `type="text"`

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie well, yes that is intended.

Comment: @SebastianSimon but this doesn't make sense for me. There was a decision made that inline elements can't have `height` attributes and others (not `inline`) can. What is the point of removing the `height` attribute if CSS can style it anyway it?

Comment: @Aaron3219 Not every non-inline element has a `height` attribute, and `<img>` is an inline element which has a `height` attribute. No such decision has been made. Again, not every attribute has a corresponding CSS property and vice-versa. The fact that a `height` attribute isn’t applicable has nothing to do with whether a `height` CSS property should exist for an element.

Comment: _“Again, not every attribute has a corresponding CSS property”_ — Of course not. So maybe I need to ask another question. Why has the `img` a `height` attribute and `input` tags don't? Leave out the CSS. We are talking plain HTML.

Comment: simply because it was defined like that. Can you use `colspan` attribute with any element? for sure not, only with element defined to use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to refer to [the official specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) if you want accurate information. From there you can read that there is attributes called Global attributes that apply to all the elements:

> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on all HTML elements (even those not defined in this specification) ...

And if you continue reading you find that there is specific attribute related to some specific elements. There is no *magic* rule and everything is well defined.

> The **width** and **height** attributes on `img`, `iframe`, `embed`, `object`, `video`, and, when their type attribute is in the Image Button state, `input` elements may be specified to give *the dimensions of the visual content* of the element (the width and height respectively, relative to the nominal direction of the output medium), in CSS pixels. The attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers. <sup>[ref](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dimension-attributes)</sup>

Here you can see where the `height` attribute can be used. The difference with the CSS property is that this one will specify the dimension that the browser should reserve to that element. You can of course change it later with CSS and if you omit it, a default value will be used (also defined in the same spec).

> User agent requirements: User agents are expected to use these attributes as **hints for the rendering.**

The height/width attrbiutes can also be used with SVG and Canvas:

> The canvas element has two attributes to control the size of the element's bitmap: width and height. These attributes, when specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers. The rules for parsing non-negative integers must be used to obtain their numeric values. If an attribute is missing, or if parsing its value returns an error, then the default value must be used instead. The width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150.

---

Well, an anwser won't be enough to talk about everything related to height attribute but in the specification you can find for each item the attributes that you can use and how they behave. From this you can find the exhaustive list of element where the height attribute is allowed.

Example:

[image: canvas element]

---

When it comes to CSS, you should refer to [the specification related to the height property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property) to get more details about how it behaves with different type of elements.

Comment: As always, a great answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -3):

(copied from w3school)

**Definition and Usage**

The height attribute specifies the height of the  element.

**Note:** The height attribute is used only with .

Tip: Always specify both the height and width attributes for images. If height and width are set, the space required for the image is reserved when the page is loaded. However, without these attributes, the browser does not know the size of the image, and cannot reserve the appropriate space to it. The effect will be that the page layout will change during loading (while the images load).

Comment: My question isn't why my code isn't working. I know it isn't and it should just show that it doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

CSS stuff is generally classified as style in HTML. As HTML evolved, style lines grew longer and needed to be copied for each element.  CSS solved both of those issues.

So if you don't want to use CSS, then use the following:

```
<input type="text" value="I feel so thicc :(" style="height:500px;">
```

Comment: This is not my question at all. I know why my code isn't working and I know how to fix it. I have been in the business for years. Read the comments and you will get a better understanding of what I mean