# Is width/height html attribute important in non-img html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

React libraries like [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics) and [styled-system](https://styled-system.com/) are very popular and I noticed that often times the following strategy is used:

```js
import {
  space,
  width,
  color,
  top,
  position,
  bottom,
  opacity
} from 'styled-system';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Relative = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  ${position}
  ${space}
  ${width}
  ${height}
`;

const MyComponent = () => <Relative width={1}>some stuff...</Relative>
```

which is a declarative way to use `position: relative` on components. Also other css settings like width and height are used (from `styled-system`).

However I noticed that this usage will result in the `div` having `width="1"` value:

```xml
<div width="1">some stuff...</div>
```

In styled system `width={1}` means `width: 100%` however this results in `width="1"` in the actual html. I was wondering if the `width="1"` can be disregarded because technically this width value doesn't make any sense. This will probably be an issue for `img` elements because browser actually may rely on width/height html attributes but for non-img tags does this have any implications?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58226435/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif the related answer is great but my question asks if it's ok to add `width` or `height` attributes on non-`img` tags though, if there're negative consequences for including `width`/`height` on non-`img` tags.

Comment: maybe check if the validator will like this or not: https://validator.w3.org/. Other than that I don't think there is any issues doing this.

Comment: `<div width="1"></div>` indeed results in validator error: `Error: Attribute width not allowed on element div at this point.`